# Where is the mode bit?

Tags: operating-system, mode

I just read this in "Operating System Concepts" from Silberschatz, p. 18:

> A bit, called the **mode bit**, is added to the hardware of the computer
>   to indicate the current mode: kernel(0) or user(1). With the mode bit,
>   we are able to distinguish between a task that is executed on behalf
>   of the operating system and one that is executed on behalf of the
>   user.

**Where is the mode bit stored?**

(Is it a register in the CPU? Can you read the mode bit? As far as I understand it, the CPU has to be able to read the mode bit. How does it know which program gets mode bit 0? Do programs with a special adress get mode bit 0? Who does set the mode bit / how is it set?)

Comment: The operating system sets it when it does context-switching

Answer (score 22):

Please note that your question depends highly on the CPU itselt; though it's uncommon you might come across certain processors where this concept of user-level/kernel-level does not even exist.

> The cs register has another important function: it includes a 2-bit
> field that specifies the Current Privilege Level (CPL) of the CPU. The
> value 0 denotes the highest privilege level, while the value 3 denotes
> the lowest one. Linux uses only levels 0 and 3, which are respectively
> called Kernel Mode and User Mode.

(Taken from "Understanding the Linux Kernel 3e", section 2.2.1)
Also note, this depends on the CPU as you can clearly see and it'll change from one to another but the concept, generally, holds.

Who sets it? Typically, the kernel/cpu and a user-process cannot change it but let me explain something here.

**This is an over-simplification, do not take it as it is**
Let's assume that the kernel is loaded and the first application has just started(the first shell), the kernel loads everything for this application to start, sets the bit in the cs register(if you are running x86) and then jumps to the code of the Shell process.

The shell will continue to execute all of its instructions in this context, if the process contains some privileged instruction, the cpu will fetch it and won't execute it; it'll give an exception(hardware exception) that tells the kernel someone tried to execute a privileged instruction and here the kernel code handles the job(CPU sets the cs to kernel mode and jumps to some known-location to handle this type of errors(maybe terminating the process, maybe something else).

So how can a process do something privileged? Talking to a certain device for instance?
Here comes the System Calls; the kernel will do this job for you.

What happens is the following:
You set what you want in a certain place(For instance you set that you want to access a file, the file location is x, you are accessing for reading etc) in some registers(the kernel documentation will let you know about this) and then(on x86) you will call `int0x80` instruction.

This interrupts the CPU, stops your work, sets the mode to kernel mode, jumps the IP register to some known-location  that has the code which serves file-IO requests and moves from there.
Once your data is ready, the kernel will set this data in a place you can access(memory location, register; it depends on the CPU/Kernel/what you requested), sets the cs flag to user-mode and jumps back to your instruction next to the it `int 0x80` instruction.

Finally, this happens whenever a switch happens, the kernel gets notified something happened so the CPU terminates your current instruction, changes the CPU status and jumps to where the code that handles this thing; the process explained above, roughly speaking, applies to how a switch between kernel mode and user-mode happens.

Comment: Since you are saying that it is an oversimplification, could you redirect me to some tutorial, book or material to understand the subject more in depth? Thanks!

Comment: @SamBruns : For a book, I'd strongly recommend: "Computer Systems: A Programmer's Perspective" and I'd recommend checking this as well for more OS information (and more depth): 
http://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page .

Comment: @Fingolfin Is it true that the CPU has rwx access to the entire physical memory as long as the mode bit is set?

Answer (score 8):

It's a CPU register. It's only accessible if you're already in kernel mode.

The details of how it gets set depend on the CPU design. In most common hardware, it gets set automatically when executing a special opcode that's used to perform system calls. However, there are other architectures where certain memory pages may have a flag set that indicates that they are "gateways" to the kernel -- calling a function on these pages sets the kernel mode bit.

Answer (score 4):

These days it's given other names such as Supervisor Mode or a protection [ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_%28computer_security%29).